# Jenkins - Failed to connect to repository - Authentication Failed

Tags: git, jenkins, oauth, bitbucket

I've set up Jenkins and I've installed Bitbucket OAuth plugin and the Bitbucket Plugin.  I followed the instructions on [Bitbucket OAuth Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+OAuth+Plugin) page.

1. Manage Account
2. OAuth
3. Create Consumer with read permission

I then returned to jenkins and added the id and secret key to the Bitbucket OAuth Plugin.

However, when creating a new item I put in the git repository url in the suggested field but I get a Failed to connect to repository error - **Error 128**. 
[image]

Could anyone help on this?  First time setting up Jenkins so I'd appreciate any help.